# How to add External javascript library in Ionic2 Application

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-services

I am having a pure javascript library which is neither available in npm nor in any public repository.
Its a pure javascript file with extension .js. It has some functions which i need to use in my Ionic2 application.
How can i import such files in my Ionic2 Application.
Any references will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the library in `index.html` and declare its namespace in `declarations.d.ts`

Example: `declare var LIBRARY_NAMESPACE: any;`